# Moving Salt Master to a new server

Tags: saltstack

So I am tasked with migrating some servers into AWS. One of the servers is a **Salt Master**.

Upon investigation, all Salt Minions connect to the Master using DNS name instead of IP Address, so from connectivity standpoint I only need to change the A Record for the Master's FQDN.

However, I know that the Master and the Minions exchange some keys between them for authentication purposes.

How do I move the Master but maintain association? Is it enough to copy the whole `/etc/salt` directory to the new Master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, copying the `/etc/salt` directory and naming the new host the same name as the old host (*probably "salt"*) is enough.

The directory `/etc/salt` contains all of the information you might need, as well as keys within the `/etc/salt/pki` directory.

You should probably make sure the versions at least sort of match between your old and new deployments. The configuration files are self-documenting, and get updated often.